# Replace a certain part of the string which matches a pattern in python 2.7 and save in the same file

Tags: regex, string, python-2.7, replace, substring

I am trying to achieve something of this sort

My input file has this kind of entries

```
art.range.field = 100
art.net.cap = 200
art.net.ht = 1000
art.net.dep = 8000
```

I am trying to match the pattern like where `art.range.field` is there the value should be changed to `500`. So the output of the code should be something like

```
art.range.field = 500
art.net.cap = 200
art.net.ht = 1000
art.net.dep = 8000
```

Here is my following attempt at solving this problem

```
file_path = /tmp/dimension
with open(file_path,"r") as file
  file_content = file.read()
  new_content = re.sub(r"^.*"+parameter+".*$",parameter+" = %s" % value, file_content)
  file.seek(0)
  file.write(new_content)
  file.truncate()
```

Here I have taken `parameter = art.range.field` and `value = 500`.

But still my file is remaining unchanged as the `new_content` variable is not changing its value to the desired out put.

So I want to know where I am going wrong and what can be the possible solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you want with

```py
import re
parameter = 'art.range.field'
value = 500
with open(file_path,"r+") as file:
    new_content = re.sub(r"^("+re.escape(parameter)+r"\s*=\s*).*", r"\g<1>%d" % value, file.read(), flags=re.M)
    file.seek(0)
    file.write(new_content)
    file.truncate()
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XwlPhw/1).

**Note**:

- You need to use `r+` to actally read/write to a file
- `re.M` to match start of any line with a `^`
- `re.escape` to escape special  chars in the `parameter` variable

*Regex details*:

- `^` - start of line
- `(art\.range\.field\s*=\s*)` - Group 1 (`\g<1>` in the replacement pattern, the unambiguous backreference is required as `value` starts with a digit):

  - `art\.range\.field` - a `art.range.field` string
  - `\s*=\s*` - a `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing anything because you are not in multi-line mode. If you prepend `(?m)` to your regex (before the `^`) it should work. See also [this resource](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) for deepening the argument of regexp's modifiers.

Furthermore:

- You don't need `$`, since you are not in single line mode, so with `.*` you'll just match all the characters until the end of the line.
- For avoiding false positives, I would also make sure that `parameter` is followed by an equal sign.
- You'd better to escape the parameter (using the `re.escape` method) if you want to use it as part of a regex.

So you should use this line of code:

```
new_content = re.sub(r"(?m)^\s*" + re.escape(parameter)  +"\s*=.*", parameter + " = " + value, file_content)
```

Comment: Thanks I got the issue was not being in multi-line mode as I was reading the whole file. Thanks for pointing it out and the explanation.